# Table view showing up empty instead of conforming to my custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview with custom cells that holds an array of items. I initialize an empty array and some data like so

```
    var venues = [String]()
    var images = [String]()
    var nycVenues = ["Webster Hall", "Output", "The Woods"]
    var nycImages = ["Webster", "Output", "Woods"]
```

Then depending on what the title of the page is, that array is filled with the corresponding data. Here's my code in cellForRowAt indexPath

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! VenueCell


    if (self.navigationItem.title == "NYC Venues") {
        nycVenues = venues      //fill the empty venue array with nycVenues
        nycImages = images    //fill the empty images array with nycImages
        cell.textLabel?.text = venues[indexPath.row]
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.venueImageView.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])!
        }
    }
    //.....other venues set up the same way
    return cell
}
```

Number of rows in section

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return venues.count
}
```

Set the height of the cells

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 72
}
```

And here's my custom cell

```
class VenueCell: UITableViewCell {

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    textLabel?.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: textLabel!.frame.origin.y - 2, width: textLabel!.frame.width, height: textLabel!.frame.height)
    detailTextLabel?.frame = CGRect(x: 64, y: detailTextLabel!.frame.origin.y + 2, width: detailTextLabel!.frame.width, height: detailTextLabel!.frame.height)
}


let venueImageView: UIImageView = {

    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return imageView

}()

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    addSubview(venueImageView)
    venueImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    venueImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    venueImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48).isActive = true
    venueImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48).isActive = true


}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


}
```

The issue is that when the table view appears, it just shows an empty default tableview (without conforming to my custom cells, and with none of the items). Anyone know where I'm missing something?

Comment: The line `nycVenues = venues` replaces your filled array with the empty array, not the other way around.

Comment: Rmaddy is right. This is a good example of why you should use `let` rather than `var` for data that won't/shouldn't change. If you had done this then the compiler would have given you an error and you would have avoided a trivial bug.

Comment: `cellForRowAt` is also the wrong place to put that code.

Comment: Rmaddy, thanks I changed it but the issue still persists. It should be said that if I return 3 instead of venues.count in numberOfRows, everything shows up fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

As [paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11) mentioned in the comments bellow the assignment of the `venues` and `images` array should be made **before** `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)` is being called. So making the assignment in the `viewDidLoad` should fix it.

### Original

Your problem is in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`. Check the `if` statement and change these two lines

```
nycVenues = venues      //fill the empty venue array with nycVenues
nycImages = images    //fill the empty images array with nycImages
```

to

```
venues = nycVenues      //fill the empty venue array with nycVenues
images = nycImages    //fill the empty images array with nycImages
```

Comment: Well that's embarrassing.. However after making the change, the issue still persists, just showing an empty default tableview.

Comment: Also, if I change numberOfRows to return a constant, like return 3, everything shows up perfectly. But when I do return venues.count, I get the empty table view without my custom cells.

Comment: Have you changed where you are assigning the arrays?  You need to do it in `viewDidLoad`. By doing it in. `cellForRow`, the count is 0 and so `cellfrorRow` never gets called. When you return a constant count, it does get called and the array is assigned